# Exchanging code for user access token on GitHub App install

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, github-api

I am attempting to use these instructions (https://developer.github.com/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps/#identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps) to get an access_token during installation of a GitHub App.

The App requests the "Emails" User Permission.
The App has "Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation" set.

I install the app and am redirected by GitHub to my "User authorization callback URL". While serving this page, I extract the `code` parameter which is a query string parameter of the URL.

I follow the instructions from the above page to do a post request using the `request` javascript library (I've tried alternatives with no more luck).

```
  const res = request.post({
    url: 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.machine-man-preview+json'
    },
    json: true,
    body: {
      client_id: process.env.GITHUB_APP_IDENTIFIER,
      client_secret: process.env.GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET,
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: process.env.GITHUB_CALLBACK_URL
    }
  });
```

I have also tried:

- Form encoding
- Query string parameters
- Not specifying the redirect_uri (Is the reason that this is not mandatory that in the case of setting "Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation" to true, it does not apply?)
- Not specifying the special header

I have also triple checked that the environment variables are correct.

No matter what I do, I get a 404 instead of an access token.

Comment: Try using PostMan to send the request and see what you get back.  There may be an error string also.  Make sure your secret is correct and your redirect_uri has the same scheme, same case and ends/doesn't end in a slash.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried with postman/curl and triple checked the variables are exactly correct. There is no error string, I assume because GitHub don't want to leak any information if the request is not valid in any way.

Comment: The response is always the GitHub "This is not the page you are looking for" 404 html page. This seems a little odd for an API call.

Comment: I'll have to setup a test account but one thing I noticed is usually you have to specify grant_type=authorization_code and then try with the url /token instead of /access_token

Comment: any luck with this?  did you try specifying the grant_type?

Comment: Very painful as (correctly) GitHub doesn't give you any feedback if you get the id/secret wrong. I found that I was using the app ID instead of the client ID and the webhook secret instead of the client secret. I'd triple checked them... but if one triple-checks the wrong thing, it doesn't help! Thanks for the help.

I did not have to specify the grant_type